# Какие параметры передать при вызове конструктора?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть следующий конструктор

```
 public RtbService(IHttpClientFactory client, ILogger<RtbService> logger)
{
   _client = client.CreateClient();
   _logger = logger;
}
```

Когда я создаю объект, то мне необходимо указать передаваемые параметры, но я не понимаю, что мне надо передать, пробовал `new HttpClient` - ошибка, пробовал просто `IHttpClientFactory` но все равно ошибка, с логгером таже история, помогите, что надо передать в конструктор?

Comment: Вы не должны создавать объекты самостоятельно! В ASP используется контейнер, который сам за вас инициализирует все объекты, вам достаточно зарегистрировать типы и попросить через конструктор то, что вы хотите.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: К сожалению, при проектировании HttpClient были сделаны ошибки и для их решения наворочен костыль на костыле. Проще всего, действительно, взять DI-контейнер, зарегистрировать в нём дефолтную фабрику методом AddHttpClient() и далее из контейнера получить клиент.

Comment: Если вы хотите отвязаться от микрософтовского контейнера (а это ой как непросто! они привязывают к своим продуктам намертво), то смотрите реализацию [DefaultHttpClientFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs) - либо копируйте код, либо по образцу пишите свою реализацию. Также может помочь исходник [AddHttpClient](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)